# How to retrofit a slab for protection from frost heave

Tags: concrete, slab, retrofit, frost-heave

One structure on our property is built slab on grade. Located in the US in climate zone 6. This is a heated space which we will be removing part of. The removal will expose a lot of the slab to the elements.

Now, I assume that the slab is correctly constructed and has appropriate footings and is probably insulated underneath. (Assumed because we've had zero problems with it in 20+ years). However, we intend to cut away portions of the to-be exterior slab. The concern is that this will expose the slab to frost heave.

I am looking for suggestions as to how to protect it from this. Options I can think of include:
 - Adjust drainage to make sure water flows away.
 - Dig a new trench "footing" under the new slab perimeter, which presumably has to be down below front depth. (Not a load bearing footing, however - just a water diversion)
 - Dig a trench and use plastic or some other impermeable material to create a sloping surface to channel groundwater away from the slab. This would also have to go below frost depth.

These may not necessarily be mutually exclusive options. Cost is a factor, of course, but mainly I want to make sure I know how to do it correctly.

---

Edit - I think the foundation is a typical footing-below-frost-depth type. Not a shallow frost-protected design. This assumption is based on the age of the structure - built around 1990. According to this [HUD report](https://www.huduser.gov/publications/pdf/frost.pdf%20U.S.%20Department%20of%20Housing%20and%20Urban%20Development%20Office%20of%20Policy%20Development%20and%20Research%20FROST-PROTECTED%20SHALLOW%20FOUNDATIONS%20Phase%20II%20-%20Final%20Report%20-%20p17), at that time the shallow type was extremely uncommon in the US.

Comment: Is it slab on grade or is it a footing with a slab on top(you mention 'new trench')?

Comment: It is slab on grade... but I believe the way it is constructed is with a perimeter footing down below frost line (or at least deep enough for a heated slab). By cutting away some of the slab, we would also be removing some of that perimeter footing. Thanks

Comment: You expect it to be like the [image](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/490118371924716560/) on the left side rather than the right side? Also, pictures would help!

Comment: @Chris actually I am not sure if it is conventional below-frost-depth type or a shallow type. But since we would be removing a portion of the existing slab perimeter (whatever it is) I don't think it matters in that section. It will matter though in the remaining original perimeter which will then be unheated.  I'll try to cook up a diagram for this question. Thanks

Comment: From what you're explaining, the only guaranteed items you'll need are a) re-bar b) structural epoxy and c) either a concrete saw, or seam foam for joining the new footing/slab edge. Don't over think it, generally match what's there, or do better. With more information I can give a full explanation which is why I'm leaving this as a comment.